# How to get 50% records from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Suppose I have a table with 1000 rows and I want 50% of it in the output. How can I do that? Does it have any in-built function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use :

```
SELECT 
    TOP 50 PERCENT * 
FROM 
    Table1;
```

with Row_number

```
SELECT 
        TOP 50 PERCENT Row_Number() over (order by Column1) ,* 
    FROM 
        Table1;
```

**Note**: `Row_number` should have a over clause with order by column or partition by columns

Comment: Thanks... can we do it using Rownum?

Comment: @AshishKarnavat yes

Comment: @AshishKarnavat, you need to add order by clause

Comment: @Ravi, how can we do it?

Comment: `... can we do it using Rownum?` suggest you ask as a separate question - it is lost here in the comments of something that has an answer. While I'm here please note that `top 50 percent` **requires** that you use an order by clause, it isn't sufficient to just use TOP and forget to order the data

Answer (score 3):

The `top` syntax supports a `percent` modifier, which you can use:

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT *
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
select top 50 percent *
from TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

In TSQL you can use `TOP n PERCENT` but you should also order the output so that the "percentage of" is also specified, otherwise the result is indeterminate. By way of a simple example if rows are unordered (in this case the first insert is 6 not 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT)
>
> INSERT INTO mytable (id)
> VALUES
>       (6)
>     , (7)
>     , (8)
>     , (9)
>     , (10)
>     , (1)
>     , (2)
>     , (3)
>     , (4)
>     , (5) ;
> ```

This, if we simply ask for top 50 percent the output is

> ```
> select top 50 percent
>  id
> from mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> |  6 |
> |  7 |
> |  8 |
> |  9 |
> | 10 |
> ```

But if we use an order by clause then the result is more meaningful.

> ```
> select top 50 percent
>  id
> from mytable
> order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> |  5 |
> ```

It was also asked if a similar result could be determined using row_number(), so here is a method

> ```
> select
>  id
> from (
>     select
>        id
>      , count(*) over(partition by (select 1)) all_count
>      , row_number() over(order by id)         rn
>     from mytable
>     ) d
> where rn <= all_count / 2
> ```

> ```
> | id |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> |  5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f3cc5ff5a6ffddc4b7854b94559a508)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 

LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM table)
```